# Aligning UIButtons/UITextFields in the center

Tags: ios, user-interface, rotation, orientation, alignment

I know that you can align UILabels in the center by typing this code:

```
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter
```

Two questions: 1), how do you do the same for UIButtons and UITextFields? And 2), will these objects remain in the center after the device is rotated? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** UIButton has UILabel inside. You can access it via `titleLabel` property:

```
button.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

**2.** Yes, they will remain in center

**3.** You can find more info about UIButton in [UIButton's Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html).